# If my node is connected to 7 nodes and 4 of those say that a block they transmitted to me is valid will i mark it as valid?

Tags: network, nodes, validation, sybil-attack

Let's say I am a node and I am connected to 7 other nodes.

4 of those nodes transmit me a tx or a block and say it's valid.

(I am aware they do not explicitly send a message saying that something they sent is valid or not they would not send it in the first place.)

So will my node accept the block/tx as most of the nodes I am connected to agree that this "x" tx or block is valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, every node validates transactions and blocks independently according to a shared ruleset. It doesn't matter if someone creates a hundred nodes to connect to you and send you invalid transactions and blocks, your node will simply reject them and in most cases disconnect from those nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was just a bit confused after reading the full white paper. Thanks again!

Comment: In practice the ruleset may be shared, but more importantly, your node evaluates the data according to the _local_ ruleset of the software that you chose to install!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth reading the short "white paper" by  the inventor of Bitcoin in 2008. They said their objective was to create a system where one person could pay a second person without any trusted third parties.

Bitcoin does not require you to trust anyone in the Bitcoin network. You only have to trust that the second party, the recipient of the money, will deliver the goods or services you are paying for.

As Vojtěch Strnad wrote, all wallets verify all the data that can be verified. The network protocols etc are designed to make that possible.

Comment: Yes I had read the white paper. I was just a bit confused tho I was expecting this answer all along. Thanks!